When looping though a dataframe looking for string values. How do I print out rows without duplicating if the search term is found multiple times?
I am importing pandas and reading a csv file.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Me\MyFile.csv')

I am converting the dataframe to strings and making the contents lowercase
df_low = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower() if (x.dytpe == 'object'_ else x)

I'm using user input to search for strings
searchterm = str(input("Enter search term: ").lower())

looping through the dataframe and creating mask, then only returning non-empty results. I'm currently using the .upper command only due to the 'Item Number' having 3 capital letters in the beginning but, of course this is making the entire output capital but that is workable.
for item in df_low:
    mask = df_low[item].str.contains(searchterm)
    df_mask = pd.DataFrame(df_low[mask])
    if not df_mask.empty:
        print(df_mask[['Item Number', 'User Name', 'Short Description']].to_string(index=false).upper())

if df contains the following:



Item Number
User Name
Short Description
Comments




ITM-1
Leonardo
words and stuff
I wrote words


ITM-2
Donatello
guy and words
N/A


ITM-3
Frank
Technology list
Technology stack



Searching for the term 'technology' Expected Output:



Item Number
User Name
Short Description




ITM-3
FRANK
TECHNOLOGY LIST



Due to the loop, the actual output would be the following since the search term is found in both the 'Short Description and 'Comments' fields:



Item Number
User Name
Short Description




ITM-3
FRANK
TECHNOLOGY LIST






Item Number
User Name
Short Description




ITM-3
FRANK
TECHNOLOGY LIST



I tried multiple variations of .drop_duplicates but I know enough to know I don't know how to use that because I have a limited understanding where that would go in the overall code.

(x.dytpe == 'object'_ - Please fix the typos

str(input()) is redundant since input() returns a string. Get rid of the str call.

The column Long Description doesn't seem relevant so it's just taking up space. Please remove it. For reference see [mre] and How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

pd.DataFrame(df_low[mask]) is redundant since df_low[mask] is already a df. Get rid of the pd.DataFrame call.

All this output formatting doesn't seem relevant to the problem and it confused me at first glance how the output only has "technology" once per row. Just do print(df_mask).

"I'm currently using the .upper command only due to the 'Item Number' having 3 capital letters in the beginning" - If you want the original capitalization, apply the mask to df instead of df_low: df_mask = df[mask]

This question seems to be effectively a duplicate of: Most concise way to select rows where any column contains a string in Pandas dataframe? I just posted my own answer there btw.

Check out pandas "case insensitive" in a string or "case ignore". You don't need to convert to lowercase in the first place.

Instead of a loop, you can use applymap to filter rows that have the searchterm in any column:
searchterm = "Technology"

out = df[
    df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) and searchterm.lower() in x.lower())
    .any(axis=1)
]
out = out[["Item Number", "User Name", "Short Description"]]

  Item Number User Name Short Description
2       ITM-3     Frank   Technology list


Thank you very much @e-motta. I'm not familiar at all with how lambda functions work so I'll do a little more homework on this. I appreciate your answer and it worked as intended. Again, thank you.

This is not a very idiomatic way to do it. Check out Most concise way to select rows where any column contains a string in Pandas dataframe? and pandas "case insensitive" in a string or "case ignore".
